# How to create a scrollspy navbar-fixed-top after scrolling in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a scrollspy effect on a navigation menu in bootstrap , there is a carousel on top of the page and the navigation menu is at the bottom of the carousel . so when somebody scrolls down , after he passed the navigation menu , the navigation menu will have the navbar-fixed-top class and the viewer will see the menu .
i worked today on this problem , but i couldn't find a solution to solve this .
Here is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body class="blog">

        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="slide1" style="width:100%">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>What therefore god has joined together, Let no man seperate.</h3>
                <p>&ndash; The Bible : Mark 10:9 &ndash;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="slide2" style="width:100%">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum Header Dolor Sit Amet</h3>
                <p>&ndash; John Doe &ndash;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="slide3" style="width:100%">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Header Slider 3 Caption Text</h3>
                <p>&ndash; Holy Themeforest : Wordpress Category &ndash;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

<header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Time</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">From the Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">RSVP</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

    </header>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the functions.js :

```
// =============== Menu setup =============== //

    // checks if menu should be fixed
        function setup_menu(){
            if( !jQuery('body').hasClass('blog') && !jQuery('body').hasClass('single') && !jQuery('body').hasClass('archive') && !jQuery('body').hasClass('search') ){
                if(!$menu) $menu = jQuery(".navbar");
                if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 200 && !$menu.hasClass("navbar-fixed-top") ){
                    $menu.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                } else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= 200 && $menu.hasClass("navbar-fixed-top")) {
                    $menu.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                }

        }

// =============== Menu setup END =============== //
```

Also, I want to create a scrollspy effect for scrolling to sections, something like this : http://bit.ly/1hrjDZB how should i do this?

Answer (score 2):

1) Add an ID to your nav element

```
<nav id="yourID" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
```

2) Add the following script to your site.

```
<script>
    function stickyNav() {

        if (window.pageYOffset > 20) {
            var x = document.getElementById('yourID');
            x.className = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top";
            } 
        else if (window.pageYOffset <= 20) {
            var x = document.getElementById('navigate');
            x.className = "navbar navbar-default";
            }
        }
    window.onload = stickyNav;
</script>
```

3) Call the function with an onscroll event on your body element.

```
<body onscroll="stickyNav(this)">
```

4) Adjust the value of window.pageYOffset to needs.

*Note: this doesn't take into account your other functions' if/then statements. Adjust the above script to your needs.